# Encoding problems running jsp web pages on Apache Tomcat

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat, encoding, web

Sorry for my English. 
I'm not a web page developer - I use already created `jsp` (I can not change them by my own), placing them together with different URL parameters - that way I create some complicated web project.

I have been using `Apache Tomcat` for a long time and had an error - cyrillic (cp1251) symbols doesn't show well in some places (not everywhere!) of project. Developers of jsp said, that it is a bug and they will fix it. Time goes by, but they do not.

Recently, I have imported EAR as project in Eclipse, created Tomcat server there. Before that I read this article:
http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseWTP/article.html
and installed all soft, specified in article to be able to work well with Tomcat project in Eclipse.

And I noticed, that when I publish project to Tomcat Server (created in Eclipse - it has it's own server) I had no errors with encoding! I think this is somehow connected to Eclipse & Eclipse Tomcat Server settings.

Question: Can I copy this settings to a real Tomcat Server (not Eclipse) for correct encoding everywhere? And what are this settings?

Comment: Did you use same Tomcat versions both times ? I mean from eclipse and from out side. You said that "in Eclipse - it has it's own server" Eclipse allows you choose Tomcat Sever location. What did you choose ?

Comment: I use same Tomcat versions - v6.0 for both. I don't remember if there was action in Eclipse - to specify Tomcat location, but if it was, I specified same location. Eclipse is on the same PC, as Tomcat for real server for now. But eclipse has it's own config files:
catalina.policy,
catalina.properties,
context.xml,
server.xml,
tomcat-users.xml,
web.xml

Answer (score 1):

I also had a similar problem. My war was running on Eclipse Tomcat but when deployed manually on Tomcat, some web service involving currency symbol was facing encoding issues. Eclipse Indigo has some encoding for server.

This can be seen/edited through Run Configrations -> Common Tab. Changing this attribute produced consistent results for manual deploy and Eclipse deploy. I am not sure what this encoding is of, but it may set JVM's encoding.